# Get Windows commands to start and stop a service in LabVIEW?

Tags: service, labview, windows-messages

I would like to know **(I).** what commands the **Windows** sends to **services** to **stop** or **start** them and **(II).** how can I get those messages/command in **LabVIEW**?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to stop a service from labview, or run your labview exe as a service itself?

Answer (score 0):

Use [System Exec.vi](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/glang/system_exec/) to execute [the NET command](https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/essential-tools-for-windows-services-net-command/).

Comment: Yes! Some more examples/approaches here: https://superuser.com/questions/1214613/how-to-stop-service-from-commandline-in-windows

Comment: The question says *how can I **get** those messages/command in LabVIEW?*. I think they want to run LabVIEW code as a service.